# Problem with gets function on array of strings in C

Tags: arrays, string, pointers, gets

A few line of code bellow.
When program execute  I can input only 2 string without problem regardless what number is n, and then input loop stops. It shows ''Input 3. string'', ''Input 4. string'' etc but without possibility to enter data.
I have more code after this and everything works fine for first 2 strings but as I said I can't enter third and latter strings.

```
int n,i;

printf("Number of strings is: ");scanf("%d%*c",&n);

char **str=malloc(sizeof(char*)*n);

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    printf("Input %d. string: ",i+1);gets(str[i]);
}
```

Im not sure if the problem is in memory alocation or in gets function....
Generaly I need to pass array of entered strings into function and then process each string.

Function prototip is:
void func(char **str, int n);

Comment: Do NOT use `gets()` in C or C++. Ever. See the description of the [tag:gets] tag. Forget that this function exist. Even a Fortran programmer like me knows that this C function shall not be touched.

Answer (score 0):

Solved...
Beside allocation memory for array of pointers, as I write above, I need also to allocate memory for each string, so I need for example this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {                   
str[j] = (char *)malloc(100); }
```